# Mixing yield and return. `yield [cand]; return` vs `return [[cand]]`. Why do they lead to different output?

Tags: python, recursion, generator, yield, yield-from

Why does

```
yield [cand]
return
```

lead to different output/behavior than

```
return [[cand]]
```

## Minimal viable example

- uses recursion
- the output of the version using `yield [1]; return` is **different** than the output of the version using `return [[1]]`

```
def foo(i):
    if i != 1:
        yield [1]
        return
    yield from foo(i-1)    

def bar(i):
    if i != 1:  
        return [[1]]
    yield from bar(i-1)

print(list(foo(1))) # [[1]]
print(list(bar(1))) # []
```

## Min viable counter example

- does not use recurion
- the output of the version using `yield [1]; return` is the **same** as the output of the version using `return [[1]]`

```
def foo():
    yield [1]
    return

def foofoo():
    yield from foo()

def bar():
    return [[1]]

def barbar():
    yield from bar()

print(list(foofoo())) # [[1]]
print(list(barbar())) # [[1]]
```

---

## Full context

I'm solving [Leetcode #39: Combination Sum](https://leetcode.com/problems/combination-sum/) and was wondering why one solution works, but not the other:

#### Working solution

```
from functools import cache # requires Python 3.9+

class Solution:
    def combinationSum(self, candidates: List[int], target: int) -> List[List[int]]:
        @cache
        def helper(targ, i=0):
            if i == N or targ < (cand := candidates[i]):
                return
            if targ == cand:
                yield [cand]
                return
            for comb in helper(targ - cand, i):
                yield comb + [cand]
            yield from helper(targ, i+1)
        
        N = len(candidates)
        candidates.sort()
        yield from helper(target)
```

#### Non-working solution

```
from functools import cache # requires Python 3.9+

class Solution:
    def combinationSum(self, candidates: List[int], target: int) -> List[List[int]]:
        @cache
        def helper(targ, i=0):
            if i == N or targ < (cand := candidates[i]):
                return
            if targ == cand:
                return [[cand]]
            for comb in helper(targ - cand, i):
                yield comb + [cand]
            yield from helper(targ, i+1)
        
        N = len(candidates)
        candidates.sort()
        yield from helper(target)
```

#### Output

On the following input

```
candidates = [2,3,6,7]
target = 7
print(Solution().combinationSum(candidates, target))
```

the working solution correctly prints

```
[[3,2,2],[7]]
```

while the non-working solution prints

```
[]
```

---

I'm wondering why `yield [cand]; return` works, but `return [[cand]]` doesn't.

Comment: And of course, having written an answer, I realize this is a duplicate. The duplicate realized how to manually advance a generator, which you didn't try, but both sum up to "Why does `return` not work when used in a function that also contains `yield`?" I'll leave the answer since it goes into some details that might be useful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a generator function, `return` just defines the value associated with the `StopIteration` exception implicitly raised to indicate an iterator is exhausted. It's not produced during iteration, and most iterating constructs (e.g. `for` loops) intentionally ignore the `StopIteration` exception (it means the loop is over, you don't care if someone attached random garbage to a message that just means "we're done").

For example, try:

```
>>> def foo():
...     yield 'onlyvalue'  # Existence of yield keyword makes this a generator
...     return 'returnvalue'
...

>>> f = foo()  # Makes a generator object, stores it in f

>>> next(f)  # Pull one value from generator
'onlyvalue'

>>> next(f)  # There is no other yielded value, so this hits the return; iteration over
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
StopIteration                            Traceback (most recent call last)
...
StopIteration: 'returnvalue'
```

As you can see, your `return` value does get "returned" in a sense (it's not completely discarded), but it's never seen by anything iterating normally, so it's largely useless. Outside of rare cases involving using generators as coroutines (where you're using `.send()` and `.throw()` on instances of the generator and manually advancing it with `next(genobj)`), the return value of a generator won't be seen.

In short, you have to pick one:

1. **Use `yield` *anywhere* in a function, and it's a generator** (whether or not the code path of a particular call ever reaches a `yield`) and `return` just ends generation (while maybe hiding some data in the `StopIteration` exception). No matter what you do, calling the generator function "returns" a new generator object (which you can loop over until exhausted), it can never return a raw value computed inside the generator function (which doesn't even *begin* running until you loop over it at least once).
2. **Don't use `yield`, and `return` works as expected (because it's not a generator function).**

---

As an example to explain what happens to the `return` value in normal looping constructs, this is what `for x in gen():` effectively expands to a C optimized version of:

```
__unnamed_iterator = iter(gen())
while True:
    try:
        x = next(__unnamed_iterator)
    except StopIteration:  # StopIteration caught here without inspecting it
        break              # Loop ends, StopIteration exception cleaned even from sys.exc_info() to avoid possible reference cycles

    # body of loop goes here

# Outside of loop, there is no StopIteration object left
```

As you can see, the expanded form of the `for` loop *has* to look for a `StopIteration` to indicate the loop is over, but it doesn't use it. And for anything that's not a generator, the `StopIteration` never has any associated values; the `for` loop has no way to report them even if it did (it has to end the loop when it's told iteration is over, and the arguments to `StopIteration` are explicitly not part of the values iterated anyway). Anything else that consumes the generator (e.g. calling `list` on it) is doing roughly the same thing as the `for` loop, ignoring the `StopIteration` in the same way; *nothing* except code that specifically expects *generators* (as opposed to more generalized iterables and iterators) will *ever* bother to inspect the `StopIteration` object (at the C layer, there are optimizations that `StopIteration` objects aren't even produced by most iterators; they return `NULL` and leave the set exception empty, which all iterator protocol using things know is equivalent to returning `NULL` and setting a `StopIteration` object, so for anything but a generator, there isn't even an exception to inspect much of the time).